# Apache Tomcat Application Sefrver handles the Threading or not

Tags: tomcat

Can any one tell me whether apache tomcat application server itself manages the threading or we have to externally do that as i am not using any J2EE framework

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean.

Does Tomcat manage a pool of worker threads to handle incoming requests? Yes, absolutely, and you can configure the size of the pool.

If this is not what you are asking, please be more specific.